# Javascript / jQuery word counter with respect to markdown syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, markdown, word-count

I'm looking for word counter solution where the word counter repects the markdown syntax.

Example of markdown syntax

```
# h1 title

## h2 subtitle

Paragraph

 - A list
 - List
```

I have found http://sachaschmid.ch/Countable/ but it counts "#" as a word.

**Question**

- Is there a solution ready where the word counter respects markdown syntax. It should ignore the syntax and count the words.
- If not, how is this solved? Replacing? Excluding? Example?

Answer (score -1):

In JS, you simply can use the split method for count words in strings:

```
"- A list".split(" ")
```

If you want to memove the unneeded symbols, you can simply remove them before doing the split using 'replace' and regular expressions:

```
"- A list".replace(/^#+\s/g, '')  // this will match any '#' character at the beginning of every line
```

Comment: Ok, so I should repeat this line for every beginning character that I need to replace? (/^-+\s/g, '')

Comment: No, if you use the /g flag you only need to invoke it once. Remove it if you want only the first match replace.